# Deactivate jQuery stick navigation once a specific div is scrolled to

Tags: jquery, html, navigation, scroll

I have two instances of divs being converted from position relative to position fixed once the scrollTop is reached. However, i'm looking for a way to switch off one function once a footer div is scrolled to. If you take a look at the sidebar on this page, you can get a better understanding as to what i'm trying to achieve, http://staging.alcoholrehab-florida.com/alcohol-rehab-programs.html

Once the page reaches the bottom footer div, i need to set the sidebar back to position:relative in order for it not to cover up the rest of the page and be able to scroll up along with the content section.

Below is the current jQuery script i am using. Any help or advice is greatly appreciated!

```
    <script>
    $(function() {

// grab the initial top offset of the navigation 
var sticky_navigation_offset_top = $('#sticky_navigation').offset().top;

// our function that decides weather the navigation bar should have "fixed" css position or not.
var sticky_navigation = function(){
    var scroll_top = $(window).scrollTop(); // our current vertical position from the top

    // if we've scrolled more than the navigation, change its position to fixed to stick to top, otherwise change it back to relative
    if (scroll_top > ( sticky_navigation_offset_top - 120 )) { 
        $('#sticky_navigation').css({ 'position': 'fixed', 'top':120, 'background':'#f0f0f0' });
        $('.container').css({ 'position': 'relative', 'top':144 });
        $('.sidebar').css({ 'position': 'fixed', 'top':264 });
    } else {
        $('#sticky_navigation').css({ 'position': 'relative', 'top':0, 'background':'#fff' });
        $('.container').css({ 'position': 'relative', 'top':60 });
        $('.sidebar').css({ 'position': 'relative', 'top':0 });
    }  
};

// run our function on load
sticky_navigation();

// and run it again every time you scroll
$(window).scroll(function() {
     sticky_navigation();
});

    });
    </script>
```

Comment: The example you sent doesn't work in firefox.  The sidebar still covers the footer: http://imgur.com/o9MQrkb

Comment: Right, that's what i'm trying to fix. Since the sidebar is fixed, it will cover up all other divs. I'm looking to have it's position changed back to relative once the top of the footer is scrolled to. Unfortunately i do not know how to code jQuery.

Comment: Like I said in my answer, you don't want it to revert to relative otherwise it'll jump up and out of the window (back to the top).  That's very startling for the user.  What you want to do is attach function to the window scroll event, and each time the page scrolls, calculate how far from the bottom you are, and if it's within the range where the sidebar is going to overlap, assign a negative top position to the sidebar.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to measure the window height and the document height.  Once the page scrolls down to a value that is greater than (document height - window height), you'll know you have reached the bottom.  Then just add the footer height, and if the scrollTop is greater than that, you don't need to switch it back to relative as that would jump it to the top of the page, just give it a negative top position (relative) that will give the impression that it's being held above the footer's top edge.

I'm sorry I don't have a code example, but hopefully the logic above will help you figure out when you're at the bottom, and how to offset the sidebar to keep it from touching the footer.

Comment: That is actually what i'm looking to do and the logic is perfect. However, I'm not familiar enough with jQuery to be able to code it on my own. Was hoping someone might be able to customize the code i already have in place to be able to accomplish this.

Comment: I see.  Ok, well if you can set up a jsfiddle, I can take a stab at it.  Also, it's best to declare your functions outside of the documen.load event.

Comment: This is my first attempt at creating a jsfiddle, so please bear with me. But this should work. Thanks. JQuery code was not working properly when i place it inside the javascript section, so i left it in the html.
http://jsfiddle.net/WDfjX/

Answer (score 0):

I've always used this plugin for sticky elements or just detecting when user scrolled to a certain element:
http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/